# Can I have several public directories configured for only one VERCEL deployment?

Tags: deployment, web-deployment, vercel

I have a Monorepo that holds different proyects that are related within each other and they shared some common dependencies, so it make sense to have them all together coupled inside the same Mono. I have a build process that runs inside vercel which iterates through each build step of all the workspaces. The build cache here helps me to just rebuild the proyects that needs to. Everything is ok here.

But, there is not too much customization I found on Vercel on how I could define multiple Public Directories. So, to be more graphical with this ..

MONOREPO

-----Workspace A
--------src/
--------dist/

-----Workspace B
--------src/
--------dist/

-----Workspace C
--------src/
--------dist/

So my Public Directory here is /**/dist/, but I'm not sure if a Pattern (globs, regex, etc) is accepted as an input value. I could also have a Public Workspace for the all the builds living outside of each workspace and place every build compilation inside there using a subdirectory structure but first I would like to know if using a Pattern is possible with vercel.

Comment: Does this example help? https://github.com/vercel-solutions/monorepo

Comment: @leerob I prevent a rebuild already with the build tool  (this case webpack) which I'm also thinking of using it to solve my problem with the PublicPath feature. Seems that I cannot customize vercel too much on here.